# Best practice for toggle with duration in react js

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, npm

I am using React in my web application.

I already know how to write the logic of the toggle - keeping a boolean data in my state and change it when I handle the toggle trigger.

My problem is how to perform an animation with that toggle.
I found some ideas/practices:

1. $(this.refs.slide).slideDown();
2. $(React.findDOMNode(this)).stop(true).fadeOut({
           duration: 1200,
           complete: function() {
               that.props.onComplete();
           }
       });
3. download via npm a specific module.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

React provides addons to do that. [Animation in React](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/animation.html).

Comment: I saw this documentation. I found it difficult to understand. Do you have a solid example? - @goldbullet

Comment: You can either rely on CSS to do animation in which you use the high-level API: CSSTransitionGroup. If you want to do something manually like using Velocity or some animation library, you would use the low-level API TranstionGroup.